# Rails has_many nested attributes + paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, nested-forms

I have this model:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
    acts_as_taggable
    has_many :documents, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :documents
end
```

and this model:

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :project,inverse_of: :document, dependent: :destroy
    has_attached_file :document, styles: {thumbnail: "60x60#"}
    validates_attachment :document, content_type: { content_type:     "application/pdf" }
end
```

This is my methods of the `projects_controller.rb` file:

```
def new
    @project = Project.new
    @project.documents.build 
end
def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:title, :resume, :documents => [:id,:name,:description,:date,:local,:document],
end
```

This is my index view of the project:

```
<td><%= project.title %></td>
 <td><%= project.resume %></td>
 <td><%= project.documents.name %></td>
 <td><%= project.documents.description %></td>
 <td><%= project.documents.date %></td>
 <td><%= project.documents.local %></td>
 <td><%= project.documents.document_file_name %></td>
 <td><%= link_to 'Download', project.documents.document.url(:original, false) %> </td>
```

When I create a document in document view, the document is created, but when I want to create the documents attributes in the project view it gives me this error:

> undefined method 'description' for ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `:documents => [:id,:name,:description,:date,:local,:document]` should be `:documents_attributes => [:id,:name,:description,:date,:local,:document]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `projects_controller.rb` file in `project_params` method change `:documents` to `:documents_attributes`:

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:title, :resume, :documents_attributes => [:id, :name, :description, :date, :local, :document])
end
```